# curl command is not getting executed from jenkins

Tags: curl, jenkins

### Execution of the basic curl command from Jenkins is getting failed with below error: not found

**I am executing this command using "Execute Shell" option of the build**

**Output:**
Building on master in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\TestJob
[TestJob] $ sh -xe C:\Windows\TEMP\jenkins7077488455971906369.sh
+ echo Hello World
Hello World
+ curl --version
curl: C:\Windows\TEMP\jenkins7077488455971906369.sh 4: not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE

Answer (score 0):

Windows system doesn't come with curl.The script which you trigged run on Powershell. What you will need to do is download and have the curl.exe file somewhere in C: directory and a**dd that executable file location to the PATH environment variable**. Alternatively, you can use **Invoke-WebRequest method** below is the URL for the Invoke-Web request documentation

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-6